# How to add class to fieldset?

Tags: zend-framework2, fieldset, zend-form2

I have a form in ZF2 with the following element being added:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'animals',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'animals',
        'class' => 'form-control',
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Favourite animal',
        'options' => array(
            'cat' => 'Cat',
            'dog' => 'Dog',
            'fish' => 'Fish',
        ),
    ),
));
```

And in my view script I have the folloing line:

```
<?php echo $this->formrow($form->get('animals')); ?>
```

Which is generating the following html:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Favourite Animal</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="animals" id="animals" class="form-control input-error" value="cat">Cat</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="animals" class="form-control input-error" value="dog">Dog</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="animals" class="form-control input-error" value="fish">Fish</label>
</fieldset>
```

How do I add a class to the fieldset?

I have tried adding the following to the `options` array, the `attributes` array, and as an option to the main array but it is not adding the class to the fieldset:

```
'fieldset_attributes' => array(
    'class' => 'form-group',
),
```

### [edit]

Looking into the code (`\Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow::render`) I've found this:

```
...
// Multicheckbox elements have to be handled differently as the HTML standard does not allow nested
// labels. The semantic way is to group them inside a fieldset
if ($type === 'multi_checkbox'  || $type === 'radio' || $element instanceof MonthSelect ) {
    $markup = sprintf('<fieldset><legend>%s</legend>%s</fieldset>', $label, $elementString);
} 
...
```

Which means the only way to add a class to the fieldset (or legend if you wanted) is to extend the view helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the answer as posted [here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27273068/351785)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27273068/351785).

From the answer (modified to suit my requirements):

> Create the `Application\Form\View\Helper\FormRow.php` helper class like
>   below:
>
> ```
> <?php
> /**
>  * Extend zend form view helper formrow to allow class to be added to fieldset / legend
>  */
> namespace Application\Form\View\Helper;
> use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow as ZendFormRow;
>
> class FormRow extends ZendFormRow
> {
>
>     /**
>      * Utility form helper that renders a label (if it exists), an element and errors
>      *
>      * @param  ElementInterface $element
>      * @throws \Zend\Form\Exception\DomainException
>      * @return string
>      */
>     public function render(\Zend\Form\ElementInterface $element)
>     {
>         //... other code here
>
>             // Multicheckbox elements have to be handled differently as the HTML standard does not allow nested
>             // labels. The semantic way is to group them inside a fieldset
>             if ($type === 'multi_checkbox'
>                 || $type === 'radio'
>                 || $element instanceof MonthSelect
>             ) {
>                 $fieldset_class = $legend_class = '';
>                 if($class = $element->getOption('fieldset_class')) {
>                     $fieldset_class = sprintf(' class="%s"', $class);
>                 }
>                 if($class = $element->getOption('legend_class')) {
>                     $legend_class = sprintf(' class="%s"', $class);
>                 }
>                 $markup = sprintf(
>                     '<fieldset%s><legend%s>%s</legend>%s</fieldset>',
>                     $fieldset_class,
>                     $legend_class,
>                     $label,
>                     $elementString);
>             }
>         //... other code here
>
>         return $markup;
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> And override the factory in the onBootstrap() method of the Module.php
>   file like below:
>
> ```
> namespace Application;
>
> use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
> use Zend\View\HelperPluginManager;
>
> class Module
> {
>     /**
>      * On bootstrap for application module.
>      *
>      * @param  MvcEvent $event
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
>     {
>         $services = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
>
>         // The magic happens here
>         $services->get('ViewHelperManager')->setFactory('formrow', function (HelperPluginManager $manager) {
>             return new \Application\Form\View\Helper\FormRow();
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```

And add the classes as such:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'animals',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'animals',
        'class' => 'form-control',
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Favourite animal',
        'fieldset_class' => 'form-group', //<== this
        'legend_class' => 'form-legend',  //<== and this
        'options' => array(
            'cat' => 'Cat',
            'dog' => 'Dog',
            'fish' => 'Fish',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: In ZF3 no need for injecting the magic in module's onBootstrap method. This can be done in module.config.php in view_helper configuration section.